# Unable to delete content resources on JasperReports Server

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I'm using JasperReports Server 5.6 and I have some reports deployed there.

**The problem starts when I generate a PDF output for my reports. I can see the output file in the repository, but I'm unable to delete it**.

I'm able to delete other types of resources, as an image or report, for example. But when I need to delete a generated PDF, the upper options bar doesn't offer me any options (including deleting). If I try to right-click the PDF, it doesn't open any pop-up menus (as it does for images, for example).

The image below shows what happens to the options bar:
[image]

Here goes some interesting things I've noticed:

- The type column in the repo tells me the PDF is a "Content Resource". If I manually upload another PDF from my local machine to the repo as a "Content Resource", the UI also doesn't let me delete the resource.
- I'm logged in as the administrator user. It's set with ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMINISTRATOR roles (it's the default jasperadmin user).
- The directory which contains the PDF is set with permissions Read+Write+Delete for the ROLE_USER.
- Tried to log in as another user with ROLE_USER and I got the same result.
- The JasperReports Server's tomcat is running as root (it's a test environment).
- I went through the JasperReports Server's User's Guide and Administrator's Guide. Both said that I need to have the right permissions (and I do), and also I need to have no references to the resources to be deleted. In the case above, where I have an uploaded PDF as a "Content Resource", I don't have any references to it inside the repo, and I still can't delete it!
- If I delete the super directory that contains the PDF, it works fine.

So, do you guys have any ideas of what I can try to get rid of these PDF outputs?

Answer (score 5):

So far the best solution, I didn't find any better, for this is to use the **delete button on the keyboard**

I really don't know why is the menu button disabled but nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same problem. There is a work around for this: Use Jaspersoft Studio.
Add a JasperReports Server Connection, expand the node and locate the file you wanted, then right-click and select Delete.

This is not an elegance solution but works for the moment.

Comment: Definately an interisting workaround. Thanks Kaayan.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT - found the problem and have a fix.**

The JS is missing "Utils" scope in getInitConfiguration.  The original source is:

```
var Utils = {
restOfString: function(str, fromStr) {
    var from = str.lastIndexOf(fromStr) + fromStr.length;
    return str.substring(from, str.length).trim();
},
getInitOptions: function () {
    return localContext.rsInitOptions || __jrsConfigs__.repositorySearch["localContext"].rsInitOptions;
},
getInitConfiguration: function () {
    return getInitOptions().configuration;
}
```

};

Just change "return getInitOptions().configuration;" to get "return Utils.getInitOptions().configuration;"

You'll have to make this change in the optimized version of the script (optimized-scripts/results.page.js).  Fortunately there are only two occurrences of getInitOptions so it's easy to find and fix the correct one.

---

The root cause is a javascript error:

```
uncaught ReferenceError: getInitOptions is not defined
```

This is coming from results.page.js, but I haven't found a fix for it yet.  This code is attempting to change the state of the toolbar buttons.  I tried using the latest 6.x version of the script, and that did not fix the problem either.

Also listed at http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/843951/unable-delete-report-output-jasperserver-56

Comment: Hey nice investigative senses. I applied the changes, but nothing changed. Subsequently peeked into the js-Sources with FF-Devtools and the "Utils."-Part wasn't added. Cleared the browser cache. Success! The full path to the specific file is in my case: /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-5.6.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/optimized-scripts/results.page.js. Upvote earned.

Comment: Is there a way to delete the multiple files in one go.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to delete the content resource Delete button show disable. I am also experiencing the same problem so for time being I am deleting my content resources by using following query on Jasperserver schema.

```
Delete from jicontentresource where id in  
(
Select id from jiresource  
where resourcetype='com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.ContentResource'
and to_char(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2014-11-25');

Delete from jiresource where resourcetype='com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.metadata.common.domain.ContentResource'
and to_char(update_date,'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2014-11-25';
```

Answer (score -1):

You have only to mark all files and then push the Delete-Button